# Replacement of String in C#

Tags: string, c#-4.0, replace, substring, console-application

I have a string "**productname-producttype-front-view.png**". I need to show it like "**PRODUCTNAME-PRODUCTTYPE front view**".

I have gone upto this much

```
string y = x.Replace(".png", " ").ToUpper();
```

Now , I am stuck...Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, what is the rule? Turn the first two or last two items to upper case?

Comment: "PRODUCTNAME" & ''PRODUCTTYPE" WILL BE CAPITAL WITH A "-" WITHIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex-based approach:

```
var line = "productname-producttype-front-view.png";
var pattern = @"^(.*)-([^-]+-[^-]+)\.[^-.]+$";
var m = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
var result = string.Format("{0} {1}", m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper(), 
    m.Groups[2].Value.Replace("-", " "));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/4izL07)

What it does:

- Parses the string into the initial part and all that goes after the last but 1 hyphen, only capturing the initial part and the 2 subparts between `-` (not capturing the extension that will be dropped)
- The intial part (Group 1) is just uppercased, while the trailing part gets all `-` turned into spaces.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - string start
- `(.*)`  - Group 1 capturing any 0+ characters other than a newline as possible (but yielding a part of a string that matches the next subpatterns)
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^-]+-[^-]+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ chars other than `-`, then `-`, and again 1+ chars other than `-`
- `\.[^-.]+` - a dot followed with 1+ chars other than `.` and `-`
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: I find your answer helpful +1 especially for the detailed pattern explanation

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `String.Split` to extract the tokens:

```
string fileName = "productname-producttype-front-view.png";
string fileNameWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
string[] tokens = fileNameWithoutExtension.Split('-');
```

Now it's easy to get the desired result with the help of LINQ and  `String.Join`:

```
var newTokens = tokens.Select((s, index) => index >= 2 ? s : s.ToUpper());
string result = String.Join(" ", newTokens);  // puts a space between each token
```